# Entity Framework: how do I run a stored procedure and return a value?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure using the Entity Framework, passing in variables and returning data along with a return value?

Please do not leave any code about function mappings with Entity Framework.

I have tried this and I keep getting the same damn error:

> Procedure or function 'usp_BusinessUser_Search' expects parameter
>   '@TotalRecords', which was not supplied.

Here's my code:

```
SqlParameter Business = new SqlParameter("Business", Search.Term);
SqlParameter Location = new SqlParameter("Location", Search.Location);
SqlParameter PageNumber = new SqlParameter("PageNumber", Search.CurrentPage);
SqlParameter RecordsPerPage = new SqlParameter("RecordsPerPage", Search.RecordsPerPage);
SqlParameter TotalRecords = new SqlParameter("TotalRecords", 0);

SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@TotalRecords",
    Value = 0,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};

var List = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ENT_SearchBusinessResult>("exec usp_BusinessUser_Search",Business,Location,PageNumber,RecordsPerPage,parm);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_BusinessUser_Search] (   @Business nVarChar(255) = NULL
                                                    , @Location nVarChar(255) = NULL
                                                    , @PageNumber Int = 1
                                                    , @RecordsPerPage Int = 10
                                                    , @TotalRecords Int OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @CacheTable SYSNAME
            , @TotalRows Int
            , @Category VarChar(255)
            , @BusinessCategory Int 
            , @TownCounty VarChar(50)
            , @PcodeTownCounty VarChar(50)

    INSERT  Voucher_SearchHistory (Keyword, Location)
    SELECT  NULLIF(@Business,''), NULLIF(@Location,'')
```

Comment: What does your stored procedure declaration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing TotalRecords  Sql Parameter in Excecute

```
var List = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ENT_SearchBusinessResult>(
"exec usp_BusinessUser_Search",Business,
Location,PageNumber,RecordsPerPage,parm);
```

Comment: parm is the same as Total records, I just thought I'd try a different approach, using the variable Totalrecords returns: 
The parameterized query '(@Business nvarchar(14),@Location nvarchar(14),@PageNumber int,@' expects the parameter '@TotalRecords', which was not supplied.

Comment: @Funky I meant it is not necessary to give @ I should have been more clear with the words, apologies mate

Comment: @Funky you are not passing "@TotalRecords" in your db.ExecuteStoreQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the following extension method, `ExecuteSqlCommandWithReturn`, that takes care of all of the work for you!

https://gist.github.com/copernicus365/7037320

```
string sql = "EXEC sp_CoolProc @SomeParam, @AnotherParam";
int returnValue;
int val = db.ExecuteSqlCommandWithReturn(sql, out returnValue, someParam, anotherParam);
```

The key to the solution was by Jieyang Hu [here](http://jieyanghu.com/2013/03/01/retrieving-a-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure-using-the-entity-framework-dbcontext-database-class/), which is this (though note that all of the following is fully handled by the aforementioned extension method): Just as you can do in a SQL prompt, you just set the result of the executed procedure to a SQL variable (in this case which is sent in as a parameter), like this:

```
EXEC @ReturnVal = sp_MyCoolProc;
```

This code adds the fragment `@ReturnVal =` after the first `EXEC` (followed by whitespace) it finds, and adds to the `SqlParameter`s (or creates `SqlParamter`s if there were none) a ReturnVal parameter, though the caller will never see these.

Comment: I tried it to get the count from 'SELECT COUNT(*)...' query, but it doesn't work. I always get a big negative number as returnValue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name should not contain `@`:

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "TotalRecords",
    Value = 0,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};
```

Comment: As per MSDN I dont think it is neccessary to give @ see example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just added that parameter ('@TotalRecords) recently 
I am going to guess that you just need to update your function import definition in your edmx model.